# Scala generic macro

Tags: scala, generics, macros

Is it possible to do the following with scala macros:

```
trait Cacheable {
  def cache[T](genValue: => Future[T]): Future[T] = macro Cacheable.cacheImpl[T]
}

object Cacheable {
  def cacheImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)
                                 (genValue: c.Expr[Future[A]]): c.Expr[Future[A]] = {
    import c.universe._

    reify {
      genValue.splice
    }
  }
}
```

It does not compile at the macro function call in the Cacheable trait with the following message:

Multiple markers at this line
- macro implementation has wrong shape: required: 
(c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(genValue: c.Expr[=> scala.concurrent.Future[T]]): c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[T]] found : (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(genValue: c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]): c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[A]] type mismatch for parameter genValue: c.Expr[=> scala.concurrent.Future[T]] does not conform to c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[?A]] - macro implementation has wrong shape: required: (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(genValue: c.Expr[=> scala.concurrent.Future[T]]): c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[T]] found : (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(genValue: c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]): c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[A]] type mismatch for parameter genValue: c.Expr[=> scala.concurrent.Future[T]] does not conform to c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[?A]]

Answer (score -1):

First of all get your signature right:

```
import concurrent.Future
import language.experimental.macros
import reflect.macros.Context

trait Cacheable {
  def cache[A](genValue: => Future[A]): Future[A] = macro Cacheable.cacheImpl[A]
}

object Cacheable {
  def cacheImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)
                                 (genValue: c.Expr[Future[A]]): c.Expr[Future[A]] = ???
}
```

The error is clear:

```
<console>:12: error: macro implementation has wrong shape:
 required: (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(genValue: c.Expr[=> scala.concurrent.Future[A]]): c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]
 found   : (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(genValue: c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]): c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]
type mismatch for parameter genValue: c.Expr[=> scala.concurrent.Future[A]] does not conform to c.Expr[scala.concurrent.Future[?A]]
         def cache[A](genValue: => Future[A]): Future[A] = macro Cacheable.cacheImpl[A]
                                                                           ^
```

You are asking for a call-by-name parameter in the `cache` method, but use an eager type in the macro implementation method.

There is no corresponding type `c.Expr[=> Future[A]]` and I very much doubt that it is possible to express such a type. Because the macro transforms the expression which evaluates to `Future[A]`, if you want to use that expression "by need" you must provide a mechanism in the AST you produce by the macro. Since your return type is `Future[A]` and not, for example, `() => Future[A]`, I don't see how you would achieve this here, or what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I wasn't looking for a comment on the validity or usefulness of the code snippet or an explaination of the error message more an answer to whether such a snippet is valid in another form.  Apologies if I didn't phrase it exactly right.